# Using OpenMP and Eigen causes infinite loop/deadlock

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen

I'm solving a much larger problem and have run into a bug when I try to use OpenMP to parallelize some loops. I've reproduced the problem with some simpler code below that mimics my own code.

The problem is that when I run the program, it will randomly go into some sort of infinite loop/deadlock (CPU is 100%, but doesn't do anything). From what I can tell from my testing, one of the threads attempts to compute the matrix-matrix product but never finishes for some reason.

I know that if you enable OpenMP, Eigen will parallelize matrix-matrix products using OpenMP . I'm also adding another parallel loop outside of this. However, this bug still occurs if I disable Eigen's parallelization by defining EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE.

I'm using gcc version 4.6.0 20101127 on MacOS 10.6.8 with Eigen 3.0.4.

I can't figure out what could be going wrong...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

MatrixXd Test(MatrixXd const& F, MatrixXd const& G)
{
  MatrixXd H(F.rows(), G.cols());
  H.noalias() = F*G;

  return H;
}

int main()
{
  MatrixXd F = MatrixXd::Random(2,2);
  MatrixXd G = MatrixXd::Random(2,2);

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    MatrixXd H = Test(F,G);

  cout << "Done!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `MatrixXd::Random` thread-safe?

Comment: In my real code, I am not calling MatrixXd::Random. Edit: I changed the code to remove the calls to MatrixXd::Random and the bug is still there.

Comment: it is not something stupid like [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWrongStackAlignment.html)? Because currently this does not look like an openmp error. I downloaded and run your program in parallel without any problems with gcc version 4.5.0 20100604.

Comment: added omp.h in the headers and compiled with `g++ -I ~/devel/libs/eigen/eigen-eigen-13a11181fc5a main.cpp -fopenmp -Wall`

Comment: I'm in a situation where I can't upgrade or modify Eigen without causing a bunch of trouble. Any idea if there's a easy workaround in client code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some debugging, I think the problem is located in Eigen. In the file `src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h` there is a function called `manage_caching_sizes` that declares two static variables:

```
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l1CacheSize = 0;
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l2CacheSize = 0;
```

Changing this to:

```
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l1CacheSize = 0;
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l2CacheSize = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(m_l1CacheSize, m_l2CacheSize)
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: I just noticed that this bug was fixed in the recent Eigen versions, thanks to this stackoverflow question, see the bugreport: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=406  So now the solution would be to update your Eigen library.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, even with the most recent version of Eigen (3.0.5). I tried the fix proposed above and it is not possible with version 3.0.5, because of the new initializers. So I made the following change :

```
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l1CacheSize;
static std::ptrdiff_t m_l2CacheSize;
#pragma omp threadprivate(m_l1CacheSize, m_l2CacheSize)

if (m_l1CacheSize==0)
{
    m_l1CacheSize = manage_caching_sizes_second_if_negative(queryL1CacheSize(),8 * 1024);
    m_l2CacheSize = manage_caching_sizes_second_if_negative(queryTopLevelCacheSize(),1*1024*1024);
}
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 PPL / parallel_for. The solution is described in

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

> Using Eigen in a multi-threaded application
>
> In the case your own application is multithreaded, and multiple
>   threads make calls to Eigen, then you have to initialize Eigen by
>   calling the following routine before creating the threads:
>
> ```
> #include <Eigen/Core>
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
> {
>   Eigen::initParallel();
>
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> In the case your application is parallelized with OpenMP, you might
>   want to disable Eigen's own parallization as detailed in the previous
>   section.